# Excel, Auto find area of insert shape

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

how could I get the area automatically when I insert a square in excel?
With below coding, I can get the msg of height & width, but I'm stuck with the area finding and show in msg.
Besides, how can the coding link to the shape I insert?

```
Dim cell As Range
    Dim Width As Long
    Dim Height As Long

  For Each cell In Selection.Cells.Columns(1)
    Height = Height + cell.Height
  Next cell

  For Each cell In Selection.Cells.Rows(1)
    Width = Width + cell.Width
  Next cell

  MsgBox "Height:  " & Height & "px" & vbCr & "Width:   " _
   & Width & "px", , "Dimensions"
```

Answer (score -1):

```
Sub AreaPixels()  
Dim cell As Range  
Dim Width As Long  
Dim Height As Long  

For Each cell In Selection.Cells
    Height = cell.Height
    Width = cell.Width
    cell.Value = Height * Width
    Next cell

End Sub
```

Comment: In question he asks for sum of heights and widths.